# I'm trying to turn audio into haptic feedback, how do I get numerical data from audio?

Tags: audio

How would I sample a song to get numerical data?

I was thinking there might be some kind of program that could do this or maybe I could interpret an audio file itself without processing it in any way.

I'm going to start with 3 haptic feedback vibration motors, one on each arm and one on the chest.

I would probably need to break that data up into different parts such as stereo left/right and base.
If I can't get multiple channels perhaps I could play different frequencies on different motors.

Once I have the data, I would have to figure out how to interpret it. I think I can figure this part out. My plan is to then take that data and copy it to a Raspberry Pi and "play" it on the vibration motors.

I don't know how fast I could get the motors to accurately go. I've played around with them a little. Maybe 1-second intervals so I may have to skip some beats in faster songs.

Comment: All the audio you can play on your computer *is* numerical data. You'll want to read up on what "PCM" is! So, that part is solved for you: anything that plays an audio file converts the stored data format to a sequence of values for the soundcard to play. So, I think you really ought to read up on the basics of digital signals :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did some more research. Ideally, I'd want to stream music from my phone to the Pi and read the stream in real-time or as fast as possible, then convert the data to signals for the haptic feedback vibration motors. I'm still looking into this to see if it would be possible. The next best option would be to convert my audio files to WAV format as it seems to be easier to work with, copy them to the Raspberry Pi, then with my program read, and "play" them.

Comment: yes. it's possible.

Comment: I found this project on GitHub - https://github.com/karlstav/cava.
I noticed someone forked it and made it work with an led strip.
I was thinking I could rework part of it or a similar project.
I'm having a hard time understanding the code though.
The backup plan is this - https://www.adafruit.com/product/2305